# AgGrid loose edit mode when data is updated

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I use AgGrid Enterprise, and allow users to edit an entire row so all cells switch to edit mode.
I also have an event listener to save the row in database when the user put the focus on a new line or outside the grid.
In the first column of my grid, i have a custom cell displaying a combo. 
When the user select a value, it should update the cell AND 3 other cells in the row.
So i use the API to refresh the 3 cells.
Doing so put the cell in view mode, i loose the edit mode and the save event is triggered.

Is there a way in edit mode, to update cell content without loosing the edit mode ??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have so far?

Comment: did you find any solution to this ? sorry its been three years but I just faced this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You said your are try to entire row and and also have custom cell with combo
but ag-grid does not work any popup editor with full row edit.
You have to remove ag-grid property `editType: 'fullRow'` and it will work.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#gsc.tab=0